# Scala Factory Pattern with Generic

Tags: scala, generics, factory, factory-pattern

I want to use Factory Method with Generics which can work with specific implementations. In service classes i want to have type safety but in controller to operate only know interface.

#### Code

I have defined different types of operation type

```scala
trait Transaction {
  val amount: BigDecimal
}
case class CreditCardTransaction(amount: BigDecimal, ccNumber: String, expiry: String) extends Transaction
case class BankTransaction(amount: BigDecimal, bankAccount: String) extends Transaction
```

and Services which can work with specific operation types

```scala
trait Service[T <: Transaction] {
  def transfer(transaction: T)
}

class CCService() extends Service[CreditCardTransaction] {
  override def transfer(transaction: CreditCardTransaction): Unit = println("pay with cc")
}
class TTService() extends Service[BankTransaction] {
  override def transfer(transaction: BankTransaction): Unit = println("pay with telex transfer")
}
```

I have created factory with concrete instances

```scala
class PaymentSystemFactory(ccService: CCService, ttService: TTService) {
  def getService(paymentMethod: String) = paymentMethod match {
    case "cc" => ccService
    case "tt" => ttService
  }
}
```

And parser to get specific transaction from external service

```scala
object Parser {
  def parse(service: Service[_ <: Transaction]) = service  match {
    case _: Service[CreditCardTransaction] => CreditCardTransaction(100, "Name", "01/01")
    case _: Service[BankTransaction] => BankTransaction(100, "1234")
  }
}
```

But that code doesn't want to compile due provided types mismatch from PaymentSystemFactory method:

```scala
object App {
  val factory = new PaymentSystemFactory(new CCService, new TTService)
  val service = factory.getService("cc") // return Service[_ >: CreditCardTransaction with BankTransaction <: Transaction]
  val transaction: Transaction = Parser.parse(service)
  service.transfer(transaction) // Failed here: Required _$1 found Transaction
}
```

I would be happy to avoid type erasure if possible due factory method call and wondered why that code doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

What you've done here (apparently accidentally?) is to create a generalized algebraic data type, or GADT for short. If you want to find out more about this feature, that is probably a useful term to search for.

As for how to make this work: The type signature of the `parse` method needs to reflect that the type of the returned transaction matches service's transaction type.

Also, you can't do `case _: Service[CreditCardTransaction]`, that won't work properly due to erasure. Use `case _: CCService` instead.

Try this:

```
object Parser {
  def parse[A <: Transaction](service: Service[A]): A = service  match {
    case _: CCService => CreditCardTransaction(100, "Name", "01/01")
    case _: TTService => BankTransaction(100, "1234")
  }
}
```

And you'll need to change the calling code too:

```
object App {
  val factory = new PaymentSystemFactory(new CCService, new TTService)
  factory.getService("cc") match {
    case service: Service[a] =>
      val transaction: a = Parser.parse(service)
      service.transfer(transaction)
  }
}
```

Note that the `match` isn't used to actually distinguish between multiple cases. Instead, its only purpose here is to give a name to the transaction type, `a` in this case. This is one of the most obscure features in the Scala language. When you do a pattern match on a wildcard type and use a lower-case name like `a` for the type parameter, then it doesn't check that the type is `a` (like it would for an uppercase name), but it creates a new type variable that you can use later on. In this case, it is used to declare the `transaction` variable, and also implicitly to call the `Parser.parse` method.

Comment: wow, I didn't know about that feature. I actually wondered while reading the code why you used a lower letter for the type. I was making a solution using type member but that solution is nicer!

Answer (score 2):

While I was making the below solution, @Mathias proposed another one that I find really nice. But I still post it as an alternative that might be interesting.

Instead of type argument (i.e. generic), you can use type member:

```
trait Service {
  type T <: Transaction
  def transfer(transaction: T): Unit
}
class CCService() extends Service {
  type T = CreditCardTransaction
  override def transfer(transaction: CreditCardTransaction): Unit = println("pay with cc")
}
class TTService() extends Service {
  type T = BankTransaction
  override def transfer(transaction: BankTransaction): Unit = println("pay with telex transfer")
}

// need to use asInstanceOf, I don't know how to tell scala that the type is safe
def parse(service: Service): service.T = service  match {
  case _: CCService => CreditCardTransaction(100, "Name", "01/01").asInstanceOf[service.T]
  case _: TTService => BankTransaction(100, "1234").asInstanceOf[service.T]
}

val factory = new PaymentSystemFactory(new CCService, new TTService)
val service = factory.getService("tt")
val transaction = parse(service) // transaction has type service.T
service.transfer(transaction)
```

Comment: Yes, a type member is another solution to this problem, but it comes with a different set of tradeoffs. My solution allows you to pass transactions around between different service instances, as long as their transaction type matches. With type members the type is bound to the instance – that's good or bad, depending on the use case.  Also note that your `asInstanceOf` problem is actually unrelated to the Scala version. The transactions need to be created by the service itself for this to typecheck. Something like `Parser.parse` isn't possible with that approach (without `asInstanceOf`).

Comment: By the way, you don't actually need the `type T = …` lines. You can instead declare the case class right there, i. e. `case class T(amount: BigDecimal, bankAccount: String) extends Transaction`. Saves a bit of typing…

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I correct my comment on `asInstanceOf`. About the 2nd one, I decided to keep declaring the Transaction class outside of the Service to follow what's proposed in the question. My main point here is to use type-member instead of type-argument to be able to have type `service.T`.